# React: Function Map doesn't work in my render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to manipulate my JSON's datas but it doesn't work. For now, my file is in local. I'll change that later. Here is my code

db.json

```
{
    "test": "true false",
    "quotesList" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "quote": "Celebrity is the religion of our time",
            "source": "Maureen Dowd"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "quote": "Nothing is permanent in this wicked world not even our troubles",
            "source": "Charlie Chaplin"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "quote": "It always seems impossible until it's done",
            "source": "Nelson Mandela"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "quote": "Music isn't for the eyes, it's for the ears",
            "source": "Adele"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "quote": "The first step is you have to say that you can",
            "source": "Will Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

Quote.js

```
import React from 'react';

/*import axios from 'axios';*/

import database from '../../db.json';

export default class Quote extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const elem = database.quotesList
    return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(elem).map((v, i) => <li key={i}>{v.id}</li> )}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Quote from '../../component/Quote/Quote'


export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello Home</p>
            <Quote />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I did few tests and I think the problem is the map() function. But I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks by advance

Comment: Unless you're never going to write code that adds/removes entries in that array, using the index as the key is not best practice -- especially since your objects seem to have an `id` that (based on the name) one would hope would be unique...

Comment: For now, I'm not going to write add/removes functions. Actually it's just a test, but i will take into account what you just told me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `Object.keys` since `elem`, your `database.quotesList`, is already an array.

Changing it to

```
{elem.map((v, i) => <li key={i}>{v.id}</li> )}
```

should do the trick

Comment: It works! Thank you Lim Jing Rong for you help! I guess I need to check again what is Object.keys

Comment: @BillyB - It's for getting the keys (property names) of an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys In this case, it was giving you the array indexes, because those are property names (arrays are objects, array indexes are property names).